# Can i upgrade Photoshop CS6 to Adobe Creative Suite 6 at a discounted price?

Tags: upgrade, adobe-photoshop, license, adobe-creative-suite

I've had a look around on the official Adobe Shop website, but I couldn't find a clear answer for this..

I am a freelance developer and I have recently purchased Adobe Photoshop CS6 through the Adobe.com (small/medium business site, volume licensing). However, after downloading and installing it a couple of days ago, I realised that I may require the complete 'Adobe Creative Suite 6' instead. Does anyone out there know if this it is possible to upgrade your purchase, and not just the specific product you've bought previously?

I guess I'm looking for something along the lines of 'Complete My Album', but for Adobe software, so that I don't end up with two copies of Photoshop.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't you give Adobe a call or write them? I'm sure they'll be happy to sell you something.

Comment: Yeah, I could.. I was just curious to see if i was missing something completely obvious on the web site before I took that road though. I would imagine that they would try and sell me the whole lot again though, if they had the chance.

Comment: it's essentially my own fault though..

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Creative Cloud subscriptions are available at a discount for those who already own CS6; you may find it a more cost effective upgrade to go straight to CC rather than upgrade to the CS6 suite of apps.

More information can be found on Adobe's CC membership plans [here](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/creativecloud/buying-guide.html).